# Java - @Inject - Nullpointer "this.xxx is null"

Tags: java, dependency-injection, nullpointerexception, quarkus, cdi

Im using Quarkus for my java project. I want to Inject a external Bean but I alway get an NullPointerException with this error message:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "xxx(yyy)" because "this.xy" is null
```

My code snippet:

```
@Service
@ApplicationScoped

public class xxx{
    @Inject
    @CXFClient
    MyClass myClass;

public void doSomething() {
myClass.methodOflcass(xxx)
}
```

I can't access to "myClass".

Comment: Is the instance of xxx injected or do you create it yourself using `new` (don't!)?

Comment: @f1sh The class is created by me and i just want to inject the class „myClass“

Comment: You need to let the framework create the instance of `class xxx` since it's a `@Service`. If the framework doesn't create it, it won't inject `myClass`.

Comment: Extra information on how do you use the class 'xxx' would help to understand the problem.